# Split string to array, including separator characters (parentheses, asterisk, dash) using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I wanted my myResult = [ '40', '-', '(', '60', '*', '2', ')' ]

```js
let myInput = '40-(60*2)';
let myResult = myInput.split(/([*\/+-])/);
console.log(myResult)
```

Comment: Parentheses in regex have to be escaped with backslash \.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include parentheses in the character set, then use `.match` instead of `.split` and alternate with numeric characters.

```js
let myInput = '40-(60*2)';
let myResult = myInput.match(/[()*\/+-]|\d+/g);
console.log(myResult)
```

Comment: Sorry, the above regex only picks up full numbers. It breaks decimal numbers to pieces. Do we add \d+.?\d+ ? to include decimals numbers.

Comment: Change the final part of the alternation to `\d+(?:\.\d+)?`